# Linked list is not printing properly (new to linked list)

Tags: c++, c++17

Im trying to print the linked list in the order it was input, so for example if i enter data sets 'a', 'b' 'c', 'd' I want to print them out in the same order but for some reason my code keeps starting at the end and traversing back? And we are not allowed to use class yet only structs

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node {
    string data;
    node* next;


};
node* addFront(node* s);
void remove(node* head, node* n);
void print(node* head);
int main() {
    node* head = NULL;

    node* temp = head;

    cout << "Enter 5 data data strings\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        head = addFront(head);

    }
    print(head);
}
node *addFront(node*s ) {
    node* person = new node;
    cin >> person->data;
    person->next =s;
    s = person;

    return s;   

}
void remove(node* head, node* n){
    if (head == n) {
        if (head->next == nullptr) {
            cout << "There is only one node and that is he head node\n";


        }
        head->data = head->next->data;
        n = head->next;

        head->next = head->next->next;


    }

}
void print(node * head)
{
    node* temp = head;
    while (temp != NULL) // don't access ->next
    {
        cout << temp->data << endl;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
```

I put data sets a, b, c, d, e and it prints out e,d,c,b,a

Comment: Actually your program does what it is: all data added to the head (e.g. when topology is `HEAD->a` and you adding `b`, you will have `HEAD->b->a`) and print starts from the head (so the first output will be the last input - like a classic stack (LIFO)). If you want queue, just write code for FIFO.

Comment: In your linked list, you only have the after pointer, for printing the list from start you also need a before pointer. You can use "two way linked list" for this purpose.

Comment: The best way that I know of to debug a linked list is by drawing pictures. Start with the empty list. Follow your coded instructions step by step to draw the list as you add items. You should see what's going on as you draw the second addition.

Comment: Your actual `print` function is fine. Though `addFront` is using "chaining"  to add to the front of your list each time -- so you list will end up in reverse order. Which is okay, but may not be what you want.

Comment: `remove` must be `void remove(node** head, node* n)` to be capable of handling removal of the 1st node (the list address will change). Since you are not returning an address to assign in the caller, you either need to pass a reference to `head` or the *address of* the `head` pointer itself.

Comment: im sorry im really new with the linked list i cant see why its a LIFO because whenever i add a node i point to the next node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that memory access violation might be occurred in print function, as the temp->next is not initialized to NULL.

```
node* person = new node;
cin >> person->data;
person->next = NULL; // preferred
```

below is one of the sample for FIFO. Just returns head pointer and find the last element every time with looping.

```
node* pushBack(node* h) {
    node* person = new node;
    cin >> person->data;
    person->next = NULL;
    if (h == NULL) {
        h = person;
    }
    else {
        node* last = h;
        while (last->next != NULL) {
            last = last->next;
        }
        last->next = person;
    }
    return h;
}
```

Or, using function parameters both the head pointer and last element pointer would be better as reduce the while loop.

Comment: `person->next =s;` in `*addFront` initializes the `->next` pointer `NULL` on its first call. For the remainder, `->next` points to the beginning of the list.

Comment: @David good point, thanks. `NULL` initialization only need to `pushBack` function which i recommended.